# how to get rid of errors in VersionInspectorLinker using GWTP?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwtp

When starting my first GWTP application I got this error message:

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
  at com.gwtplatform.common.rebind.VersionInspectorLinker.fetchArtifactVersion(VersionInspectorLinker.java:178)
  at com.gwtplatform.common.rebind.VersionInspectorLinker.checkLatestVersion(VersionInspectorLinker.java:154)
```

I could configure a proxy in the jvm args of the gwt-maven-plugin, but the problem is that other developers would need to use different proxies and we also don't have Internet connection in our continuous integration servers.

How can this checking be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Add this to your .gwt.xml file:

```
<set-configuration-property name="verifyNewerVersion" value="false"/>
```